# List in C++ Standard Template Library (STL). I made the following program and I don't know how to make a function to print the list

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <list> 
    #include <iterator> 
    using namespace std;
    class Profesor
    {
        public:
        string nume, departament;
        int grad, vechime;
    
        Profesor(string n, string d, int g, int v);
    };

    
    Profesor::Profesor(string n, string d, int g, int v) {
        nume = n;
        departament = d;
        grad = g;
        vechime = v;
    }
    int main()
    {
        list <Profesor*> profi;
        Profesor* p;
        int opt;
        string nume, departament;
        int grad, vechime;
        do {

            cout << "1.Adaugare" << endl;
            cout << "Dati optiunea! " << endl;
            cin >> opt;
            switch (opt)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Nume:";
                cin >> nume;
                cout << "Departament:";
                cin >> departament;
                cout << "Grad:";
                cin >> grad;
                cout << "Vechime";
                cin >> vechime;
                p = new Profesor(nume, departament, grad, vechime);
                profi.push_front(p);
            default:
                break;
            }
        } while (opt);
        return 0;
    }
```

Option 1 is to add a new item into the list
This is the constructor of the class
So I need a function to display the entire list
ajgnsjdgn afkajkf nskjfnakfakfnaf afnakfnasdnlang akfnafdakfrnaasf asdfkasfna
ad akjdgnakjsgsa askfnaksd asgnaskdng asdgjnsadgag

Comment: What particular problem are you having? Are you wanting to output every item in the list? If so, iterate through the list (I recommend a range based for loop, like `for (const auto* p : profi)`), then output the information you want (I recommend adding a function to the Profesor class that `cout`s each variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function to Profesor to output it's current variables:

```cpp
void output() const {
    cout << " * nume:        " << nume        << endl;
    cout << " * departament: " << departament << endl;
    cout << " * grad:        " << grad        << endl;
    cout << " * vechime:     " << vechime     << endl;
}
```

Create a function that iterates through the list and calls this function.
Here is an example that uses a range based for loop:

```cpp
void outputProfesors(const list<Profesor*>& profesors) {
    for (const auto& profesor : profesors) {
        profesor->output();
    }
}
```

Call `outputProfesors()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know how to iterate through the list.

Comment: Note that a range based for loop is short for `for (auto it = profesors.begin(); it != profesors.end(); ++it)`, or `for (list<Profesor*>::iterator it = profesors.begin(); it != profesors.end(); ++it)`